# Is std::swap() safe to use for objects?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) about copy-and-swap, there is a swap() function in the accepted answer.

```
friend void swap(dumb_array& first, dumb_array& second) // nothrow
 {
    // enable ADL (not necessary in our case, but good practice)
    using std::swap; 

    // by swapping the members of two classes,
    // the two classes are effectively swapped
    swap(first.mSize, second.mSize); 
    swap(first.mArray, second.mArray);
}
```

Why not just `std::swap(first, second)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::swap` relies on the assignment operator. So if the assignment operator were to call `std::swap`, this would lead to an infinite chain of calls back and forth between the assignment operator and `std::swap`.

Regarding the question in your title. Yes, for a well-behaved class with value semantics, it is safe to call `std::swap` on objects of that class. Only the implementer of the class cannot use it for the copy-and-swap idiom for the reason stated above.

Comment: `std::swap` does do a copy of both sides.  Manual member-wise swap only copies 1 extra member at a time at worst, and on a `std::vector` does no copies at all (of the vector's data).

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is suggested for C++98, there is another suggestion for C++11 (move semantics) in the same answer.

The reason why there is `swap()` function for C++98 solution is very well explained in Scott Meyers' Effective C++ book.

Briefly;

```
  template<typename T>          // typical implementation of std::swap;
  void swap(T& a, T& b)         // swaps a's and b's values
  {
    T temp(a);
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
```

> As long as your types support copying (via copy constructor and copy
>   assignment operator), the default swap implementation will let objects
>   of your types be swapped without your having to do any special work to
>   support it.
>
> However, the default swap implementation may not thrill you. It
>   involves copying three objects: a to temp, b to a, and temp to b. For
>   some types, none of these copies are really necessary. For such types,
>   the default swap puts you on the fast track to the slow lane.
>
> Foremost among such types are those consisting primarily of a pointer
>   to another type that contains the real data. A common manifestation of
>   this design approach is the "pimpl idiom"...